# Scrollable Tbody Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

There are many post on how to make a tbody of an HTML table scrollable.

Unfortunately, my CSS skills seem weak, because despite all those posts I have had a hard time with this.

I have a table that will be dynamically populated.  Initially it might be displayed with some blank rows.  Everything is working except that there is a worry that the data set may be large so there is a requirement that the table have a fixed height and be y-scrollable.

The HTML looks like the following.  I've added many blank rows while it is just getting laid out.

```
  <table id="output" class="gridtable">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th></th>
                <th>AA</th>
                <th>BB</th>
                <th>CC</th>
                <th>DD</th>
                <th>EE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the current CSS code that I'm trying. 
I'd like the width of the table to dynamically remain at 80% as the window changes width.

```
table.gridtable thead { 
    display: block; 
} 
table.gridtable thead tr{ 
    width: 100%; 
} 
table.gridtable tbody tr{ 
    width: 97%; 
} 
table.gridtable tbody { 
    display: block; 
    height: 200px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    width: 100%;
} 
table.gridtable { 
    border-spacing: 0; 
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
} 
table.gridtable td { 
    border:1px solid #000000;
    padding: 2px 4px; 
    height: 20px;
    width: 16.6666%;
} 
table.gridtable th { 
    background: #f2f2f2; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa; 
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 8px 4px;  
    height: 20px;
    width: 16.6666%;
}
```

This is what it looks like.  I'd like thead to be aligned with tbody rows.  Also would like the columns to be better spaced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you.

I noticed you overwrite some extra code, isn't necessary to write element before the dot, just the class is needed, and the border can have a shorthand with format `border: width style color`.

```css
.gridtable {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gridtable thead {
    display: table;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridtable th {
    padding: 8px 4px;
    width: 16.6%;
}

.gridtable tbody {
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.gridtable tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
}

.gridtable td {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    width: 16.6%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table id="output" class="gridtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AA</th>
            <th>BB</th>
            <th>CC</th>
            <th>DD</th>
            <th>EE</th>
            <th>FF</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```